# Display specific page if user signed in

Tags: php, login, conditional-tags

I have a business directory website. I'd like to know how to create a page display condition. Basically, when clicking on the "add a listing" button, how do I make non-logged-in users be directly taken to the login/sign up page instead of the "choose a listing type" page?

(*Currently, all users are taken to the "choose a listing type" page, and if not logged in, after choosing the type are asked to sign-in/sign up and then taken BACK to the "choose a listing type" page. It's a lot of unnecessary back-and-forths.*)

Comment: What is the add a listing button and how is it implemented in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter so when user comes into your website so you will redirect to them on specific page and display that specific page.

```
function user_redirect_page() {
    return site_url().'your-page-slug';
} 
add_filter('login_redirect', 'user_redirect_page');
```